# Update Foreign Key when copying records to a different table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables which I want to merge together. They both have the same columns. However, the records I want to copy over are referenced by another table.

As a result, when I update the reference to the new table, the references are no longer correct. How should I go about updating the references so that they remain correct?

EDIT - Apologies - a little more detail:

At the moment I have this:

```
INSERT INTO Suppliers
                      (Name, Reference, Telephone, Email, ContactName, AddressId, CommentSetId)
SELECT     Name, Reference, Telephone, Email, ContactName, AddressId, CommentSetId
FROM         Hotels
```

I want to delete the table "Hotels" but need to make sure the reference from another table "HotelContract" is still correct after copying the records to the table "Suppliers"

EDIT 2 - This is SQL server 2005.

I have a table "HotelContract" which has the Foreign Key "HotelId". I have updated this to "SupplierId", to be used when the hotels have been copied to the "Supplier" table.

Comment: Could you add the table structures including foreign keys to the question? Also, what version of SQL Server is this for?

Comment: Is the primary key in `Suppliers` an `identity`column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have another unique key in Hotels and Suppliers (e.g. Name) you can use this key to update SupplierId in HotelContract (drop foreign key constraint to Hotels first). You can do this with a join between HotelContracts, Hotels and Suppliers:

```
update HotelContract
   set SupplierId = S.SupplierId
  from HotelContract C
 inner join
       Hotels H
          on H.HotelId = C.SupplierId -- assuming the pk column in Hotels is HotelId
 inner join
       Suppliers S
          on S.Name = H.Name -- assuming Name is unique in both tables
```

If you don't have such a unique key you have to store the original HotelId (now SupplierId) from Hotels within a temporary column in Supplier. The update of HotelContract is simple in this case.

Restore foreign key of HotelContract afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've been stuck on this all day, and have tried a couple different ways of getting around it. However I seem to be getting a lot of "Invalid column name" errors, and I'm not sure if this is an unrelated issue?

Comment: for example, if I run this code: `code`update dbo.HotelContracts
   set SupplierId = S.SupplierId
  from dbo.HotelContracts C
 inner join
       dbo.Hotels H
          on H.Id = C.SupplierId -- assuming the pk column in Hotels is HotelId
 inner join
       dbo.Suppliers S
          on S.Name = H.Name -- assuming Name is unique in both tables`code`
It comes back with: Invalid column name 'SupplierId'.

Comment: There are two columns "SupplierId" in your code; one in dbo.HotelContracts and one in dbo.Suppliers. Please check if both tables have a column with this name? Are more columns missed? If yes please provide create table scripts by editing your questions above.

Comment: Hi, sorry had a senior moment there - I was running the query on the wrong database. Your query worked perfectly, thank you very much!